# bootstrap panel not working in angular

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get a nice border around each of an array of uploaded images.
I have tried bootstrap panels and can get them working in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CHtJMRwJD7xrM9NGZSUJ?p=preview).

However when I try to apply the same code in my angular app it doesn't work - no panel appears:

```
<div ng-repeat="f in files track by $index">
      <div ng-show="f.type.indexOf('image') > -1">
      <div class="panel panel-primary"> 
      <img ngf-src="f" class="thumb">
          <button class= "btn btn-warning btn-cancel" ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid" 
              ng-click="cancelPic($index)">Cancel</button> 
          <br><br>
          <p>{{f.name}}</p>
          <br>
          <span class="progress" ng-show="f.progress >= 0">
            <div style="width:{{f.progress}}%" 
                  ng-bind="f.progress + '%'"></div>
          </span>
      </div>    
      </div>
      </div>
```

I guess there is an obvious reason for this but I have no luck in finding it.
I am using angular 1.4.3 and bootstrap 3.3.1 same as the Plunk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the .panel-body class, like:

```
<div class="panel panel-default"> 
   <div class="panel-body">A panel</div>
</div>
```

It is strange how I didn't need the .panel-body class in the Plunk but when I added it to the app it started working. C'est la vie.